# Do I need to verify jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

So here is my scenario , I generated a jwt  token and stored that token in redis with 1 hour TTL. 
Now I see most of tutorials use jwt.verify to verify the token..

I know they are verifying the token is authentic or not

Why I need to use jwt.verify.. Why can't I use redis.exists to check the token is authentic or not..

Most of them say, we can use jwt main feature is no need to use db to check the user and expiration..

But in my scenario I cant store everything in token.. So I am using redis to store the token with session information.

Questions are
1. So I should not use jwt for this kind of scenario. 
2. Can I skip jwt.verify?

I am a node newbie..

Comment: What are you gaining from using jwt if you're also storing the token?

Comment: Thats the question.. Do I need to use jwt when there is no usage of db?

Comment: Continued discussion here, https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/issues/106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JWTs can help you quickly retrieve information about the caller, without hitting a database (redis is also a database).
When using JWTs used by client applications/external services you must always verify them to make sure that you are the one that generated them and they have not been tampered with.

Common info stored in the JWT are things like username, real name, group etc. In your scenario, you could use the JWT to store a redis key that holds the info that you want. It might be the case that you always will hit redis to get the info you want, so JWTs don't add a lot of value to your case, but it might be so that you could use JWTs to write smarter code that will only hit redis under certain circumstances eg. if the user has this right, or if we have stored something in redis about this user or not (missing redis key from the JWT token)

You are the only one that can evaluate your scenario and the usefulness of JWTs but don't be hasty to dismiss them, as they provide a nice perfomance/security improvement out of the box.

Comment: Actually i am writing a proxy server using hapi.js. I am not allowed to pass the cookies and session information sent by the downstream service, instead of that, i need to generate a token and store that info associated with it and return that token to the mobile and web browser, so they don't want handle cookies.

Comment: My Full requirement is explained here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638095/how-to-use-jwt-for-a-proxy-server-written-using-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Redis server is secured and you generate the JWT yourself (as seems to be the case here), you don't need to verify it. Once created, stored it in the cache and retrieve it later you don't need to verify it again because you know it could not have been tampered with in the Redis cache.

Only when receiving JWTs that are generated by 3rd parties you would need to verify that they are authentic.

If on the other hand you are distributing JWTs to 3rd-party applications and clients that you don't control then you will have to make sure that once you they are replayed back to you, they are untampered with by verifying the signature (or do a binary compare against the one stored in the Redis cache) and (when in use) checking the expiry timestamp in the `exp` claim.

Comment: This is not true. Verification is there to make sure that no 3rd party has tampered the JWT. So even if you generated it, if it has gone outside your servers (client browser, external service etc) it has to be verified.

Comment: Agree but the question does not suggest that it goes to 3rd parties

Comment: Most common use cases involve a client app running on a phone or in the browser. JWTs used across services inside the same infrastructure are more advanced and I assume from the question stating that he is a nodejs newbie implementing this while watching tutorials, this is not the case. You might be right, but you should state in your answer "token **received** by 3rd parties" instead of "**generated** by 3rd parties" to make it clear for everyone.

Comment: well as said that's a different use case, I've added text to describe that; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without any verification in place, it will be possible for a 3rd party to send requests to your API and in most cases the requests will likely turn into a man-in-the-middle attack. It's good security practice to keep a record of all the tokens generated on the server and then authenticate against them with each incoming request.

Comment: No need to store tokens as JWTs are signed and thus can be verified upon retrieval. If you store them, you will get other headaches, like securing access to the store and making sure it is not compromised/tampered etc.

Comment: The sign can be easily tampered with. Thus, the best practice I mentioned.

Comment: Do you have any references indicating the JWT signature can be tampered with, other than published vulnerabilities that have already been dealt with?

Comment: Unless you're transmitting the tokens over SSL, the tokens can be easily tampered with as one example. So I don't get how it's something that has been dealt with since not everyone has SSL yet or even if they do not everyone enforces it.

Comment: This is exactly why verify is needed. SSL is not required. If you tamper the JWT verification will fail, that's the core feature of JWTs.

Comment: That's what my original comment is about - why verification is important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90784/discussion-between-mxa055-and-riyadhalnur).